# The number of irreducible polynomials over ${\mathbb F}_p$

Tags: polynomials, co.combinatorics

Let $p$ be a prime number. The number of monic irreducible polynomial $P\in{\mathbb F}_p[X]$, in terms of the degree $d$, begins with
$${\rm irr}(1)=p,\qquad{\rm irr}(2)=\frac{p(p-1)}2,\qquad{\rm irr}(3)=\frac{p(p^2-1)}3,\qquad{\rm irr}(4)=\frac{5p^2(p^2-1)}{12}.$$
This seems to be the beginning of a nice sequence of polynomials in $p$. Does someone know the general formula?

**Motivation**. As F. Brunault pointed out to me, there is a polynomial $\Pi_{n,p}$ that vanishes over ${\bf M}_n({\mathbb F}_p)$. Just take the *lcm* of all the polynomials of degree $n$ over $F_p$. 
In closed form, it is the product of all the irreducible polynomials of degree $d\le n$, to the power $[\frac{n}{d}]$ (integral part). The degree of $\Pi_{n,p}$ is 
$$\delta(n)=\sum_{d\le n}d[\frac{n}{d}]{\rm irr}(d).$$
In terms of $n$, this degree is
$$\delta(1)=p,\quad\delta(2)=p(p+1),\quad\delta(3)=p(p^2+p+1),\quad\delta(4)=\frac13p(p+1)(5p^2-2p+3).$$

**Edit**. The values given above for $n=4$ are erroneous.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_polynomial

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152880/

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26031/periodic-orbits-and-polynomials

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The product of all monic irreducible polynomials of degree dividing $d$ in $\mathbb F_q[x]$ is $$x^{q^d}-x,$$
so from Mobius inversion we get the number of irreducible polynomials of degree $d$ is
$$M _d (q) = \frac{1}{d} \sum _{k | d} \mu(k) q ^{d/k} $$
This is known as the [necklace polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_polynomial).

Comment: For $n=4$, the factor $1/4$ does not coincide with Denis's $5/12$. I assume Denis made a calculation mistake?

Comment: Should be $\mu(d)$ in the sum, I assume.

Comment: And now (after the edit) it should be $\mu(k)$ in the sum, I assume.

Comment: Ah, I can't seem to type a single equation right. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks; I see the reason: $x^{q^d}-x=0$ is the equation of $K={\mathbb F}_{q^d}$ over $k={\mathbb F}_q$, and every element of $K$ has a unique mimimal polynomial.

Comment: And, as I'm sure everyone knows, in this sum for $M_d(q)$, the $q^d$ term is strictly larger than $\sum_{k|d,k>1} q^{d/k}$, which is one way to prove that for every $d\ge1$ and every prime power $q$ there exists an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$, and hence there exists a field with $q^d$ elements. 

Answer (score 14):

Gjergji Zaimi already said it all, but I want to point out a tiny bit longer but equally cute way to derive the same formula. Every monic polynomial over $\mathbb{F}\_q$ decomposes into a product of irreducibles uniquely, hence we have a formal power series equality
 $$
\frac{1}{1-qt}=\prod_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{(1-t^k)^{M_k(q)}}
 $$
(indeed, the coefficient of $t^n$ on the left is the number of monic polynomials of degree $n$, and the coefficient of $t^n$ on the right counts the decompositions into irreducibles with multiplicities). Taking logarithmic derivatives, one can do the M\"obius inversion and arrive at the formula pointed out by Gjergji.

Comment: This is of course the infinite product formula for the Weil zeta function of $\mathbb A^1$.