# A combinatorial formula involving the necklace polynomial

Tags: polynomials, co.combinatorics

This question is motivated by the answers given to my previous [one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101464). In combinatorics, the [necklace polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_polynomial) are given by
$$M(X,n)=\frac1n\sum_{d|n}\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)X^d,$$
where $\mu$ is the Möbius function.

It seems that the following formula holds true (at least, I checked it up to $n=6$):
$$\sum_{k\le n}k\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]M(X,k)=X^n+X^{n-1}+\cdots+X^2+X.$$
Is this classical. Is there any reference. Are there known applications of it ?

To me, here is an application: the *lcm* of all the monic polynomials of degree $n$ over ${\mathbb F}_p$, which is the simplest polynomial vanishing identically over ${\bf M}_n({\mathbb F}_p)$, has degree $p^n+p^{n-1}+\cdots+p^2+p$.

Comment: Replacing $\mathbf{F}_p[X]$ with $\mathbf{Z}$, the analogue of this number is $\operatorname{lcm}(1,\ldots,n)$, whose asymptotic behaviour is somewhat similar : $\log \operatorname{lcm}(1,\ldots,n) \sim n$ by the prime number theorem, see e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastCommonMultiple.html  

Comment: What does the notation ${\bf M}_n({\mathbb F}_p)$ mean? I haven't seen it before and unfortunately search engines aren't very helpful for mathematical notation.

Comment: @qbt937. This is just the vector space of matrices over the field ${\mathbb F}_p={\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By plugging in the definition of $M$ and rearranging the terms, your polynomial is
$$\sum_dx^d\sum_{m\le n/d}\left\lfloor\frac n{md}\right\rfloor\mu(m).$$
A basic property of Möbius inversion is that
$$\sum_{m\le x}\left\lfloor\frac xm\right\rfloor\mu(m)=\begin{cases}1,&x\ge1,\\\\0,&x<1.\end{cases}$$

Comment: any reference ?


Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula . If you need something printed, Möbius inversion is treated in detail in Apostol’s “Introduction to analytic number theory”.

Answer (score 2):

The LHS of your formula can be rewritten as
 $$
\sum_{k\ge 1, d\mid k}\left[\frac{n}{k}\right]\mu(k/d)X^d,
 $$
which after rearranging terms becomes
 $$
\sum_{d\ge 1}X^d\sum_{s\ge 1}\mu(s)\left[\frac{n}{ds}\right].
 $$
Let us denote $l:=\frac{n}{d}$, then the coefficient of $X^d$ in this sum is
 $$
\sum_{s\ge 1}\mu(s)\left[\frac{l}{s}\right].
 $$
Applying the M\"obius inversion in the form (see Concrete Mathematics (4.61))
 $$
g(x)=\sum_{d\ge 1}f(x/d) \quad \text{ iff } \quad f(x)=\sum_{d\ge 1}\mu(d)g(x/d)
 $$
to the functions 
 $$
f(x)=[x\ge 1]
 $$
and 
 $$
g(x)=[x],
 $$ 
we conclude that 
 $$
\sum_{s\ge 1}\mu(s)\left[\frac{n}{ds}\right]
 $$
is equal to $0$ for $1>\frac{n}{d}$ and is equal to $1$ for $1\le\frac{n}{d}$, which is precisely what your conjectured RHS says.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use $[\ast]$ both for the floor function and the Iverson bracket...

Comment: Yes this ambiguity would make this answer hard to parse for a robot. I am sure all curious robots can figure out answers for themselves ;)